# Click event on boostrap select actionsbox buttons(select and deseect all)

Tags: coffeescript, bootstrap-select

I am having a multi select with boostrap select, In which I have enabled actionsbox (select and deselect all buttons), I need to listen the click event on that buttons, 
I have tried,

```
$(document).on 'click', '.deselect-all', ->
  console.og('deslect clicked')
```

but I can't listen the button click event, Is there any other way to get the event